# Аббревиатуры: строчная-прописная

Tags: аббревиатуры

Вот интересно, аббревиатуры БАД, ДВП и т.д. пишутся прописными буквами, а вот "вуз" — строчными. Почему так?

Comment: Помню случай из времен перестройки. Партийная функционерка выдвигается кандидатом, проводит встречу с населением. И жалуется: вот, придумали слова новые, бомжи какие-то.  

Хотя это как раз советская аббревиатура, "Без Определенного Места Жительства".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы аббревиатуру начали писать строчными буквами, нужно несколько условий. Она должна легко произноситься, то есть иметь вид одно- или многосложного слова (нэп, чон, роно, гороно, сельпо, жэк, допр, врио, дот, дзот, загс...) Аббревиатура должна быть общеупотребительной и всем понятной :

> Понимаете, Бендер, случилось мне
> сидеть в тамошнем допре...

И еще один момент. На трудноуловимом уровне понимания аббревиатура должна казаться обычным словом, которое самим своим составом, буквенно-фонетическим, ясно выражает для человека суть предмета. Это достигается в случае, когда человек даже не знает расшифровки слова, никогда ее не слышал и не видел)

Ars longa, vita **brevis**

Comment: А Вы понимаете, что такое допр?

Comment: Это - архаизм.  Сейчас  это  -  обезьянник.

Comment: Допр - "предвариловка", домзак, дом предварительного заключения, сечас это следственный изолятор. "Обезьянник" - загородка перед глазами дежурного по отделению.

Comment: Правильный вариант : дом (общественно-) **принудительных** работ. Беспризорников туда сажали (см. Макаренко), бродяг всяких.

Answer (score 5):

Так закрепилось. Говорят, что уже не воспринимается как аббревиатура. Кстати, не только вуз, но и  другие слова. Самбо, например.